# My background is fixed, how do I set the scrolling at least 200px from the top of page?

Tags: css, html

My background is fixed in html, I want the page scroll to stop about 200px from the top.

```css
html, #page {
  padding:0; margin:0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image:url('images/title.png');
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #86708A;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: anything else you can give us? any html or css? something?

Comment: <style type="text/css">
   html, #page { padding:0; margin:0;}
   body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 60%;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-image:url('images/title.png');
   font-style: normal;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: x-large;
   color: #86708A;
   text-align: center;
  }

Comment: I dont know what im doing really I'm not sure what you need?

Comment: That code is good, but it needs to be in the question and formatted properly so folks can read it. This is worth a read as well: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve